# Clean curve's surface mesh preserving borders

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, svg

does Blender have any tool or add-on to clean up how surfaces formed from curves are triangulated? I have multiple curves with organic borders and need to generate clean quad meshes for them. Attached is an image illustrating the problem. The forms on the top are the curves that are from SVG files. The bottom forms are the clean meshes I manually made by extruding the edges of a simple plane and positing them so that the borders look similar. The bottom meshes also have a subdiv mod on them.[image: triangles curves x quads mesh]

Comment: Start by using a _Decimate Modifier_ set to _Planar_ (this will make all flat faces into giant n-gons. - you wont see its effects unless you are in wireframe mode in object mode) From there, you will have to find a way to get it back to quads - either manually, or with a _Remesh Modifier_ (maybe) or _Quadriform Remesh_ (also, maybe).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett thanks for the help. What worked for me was converting the curves to mesh then using the decimate set to planar as you suggested then using the loop tools space command to get all verts around the edges evenly spaced then some checked deselects and dissolve verts to remove some of the high amounts of verts then finally a triangulate modifier.

Comment: alt-F was the quickest workaround I found by following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sv9sa12d0yo&lc=Ugyc03aWlrr-OnEIKht4AaABAg.9dXz4SzlgRa9dY7BNG4p6Q